DMS migration from source - Amazon aurora MYSQL to target - RDS MYSQL failed
I am trying to migrate a single database from Amazon aurora MYSQL to RDS MYSQL using AWS DMS, but it fails and the message says
"Last Error No tables were found at task initialization. Either the selected table(s) or schemas(s) no longer exist or no match was found for the table selection pattern(s). If you would like to start a Task that does not initially capture any tables, set Task Setting FailOnNoTablesCaptured to false and restart task. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL"
I am new to DMS , please help

These are my selection rules. I tested the connection to my source and target , both were successful

I have not used convert-lowercase, however, if you want all tables to be converted to lowercase then try using:

"and Source Table Name is like" '%', convert-lowercase

Also, the rule below has always been used as a transformation rule.  I have never tested if it is actually required.

where schema name is like '%demo_database' and Source table name is like '%',
add-column

